# Type level real (floating point) numbers

Tags: haskell, types

I know that there exists the Nat type family ie the GHC.TypeLits module.

I was looking to see if there exists a similar thing for real numbers?

Comment: It's getting closed as a library recommendation question, but rephrased it is interesting I think. Rational numbers can of course be represented with two type-level nats, while any scheme you use to encode irrational numbers will be limited to a minuscule countable subset of the reals. And I guess you could implement that in terms of Nat too...?

Comment: You could probably port computable reals to the type level, but unfortunately the GHC type checker's current performance problems with type family-heavy code will likely make that impractical. I ported some of the core of `Data.Map` to `singletons`, and a map with just a few dozen entries leads to seriously slow compilation.